# Error running shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php

Tags: upgrade, enterprise-1.13

I am attempting step 3.i of the [Upgrading to and Verifying Magento Community Edition 1.8 and Enterprise Edition 1.13 - Part 1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-upgrading) instructions. The site is functioning, but when I attempt to run the URL migration script, I see this:

`[root@quantumpostcards store2]# php -f shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php - 2
[INFO]: Initialization...`

Fatal error: Call to a member function init() on a non-object in shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php on line 74

I have cleared the cache and set var/ to 777 based on previous comments, but these had no impact. Any Suggestion?

FWIW I can successfully run shell/indexer.php (php -f shell/indexer.php -- --reindexall).

Comment: Have you considered looking at the code file to see what's at line 74 which the error message makes mentioning? I'd look, but I'm on my phone ATM. ;)

Comment: My apologies, that would have been helpful. oleksii.svarychevskyi has done that for us, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php on line 74 contains code

```
Mage::getModel('enterprise_mview/client')
    ->init('enterprise_url_rewrite_category')
```

***Fatal error: Call to a member function init() on a non-object***

This error means that your script cannot create model instance of

`Enterprise_Mview_Model_Client`.

Go to `app/code/core/Enterprise` and check if `Mview` module is there.

If it is there just clear cache and try to run script again.

If it's not then you did not update you core code to **1.13.***, because **1.12.*** version has no Enterprise_Mview module.

So you cannot run **shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php** if your code/core is not **1.13.*** version.

Also check if module initialization config `Enterprise_Mview.xml` is present in `app/etc`.

Anyway make sure that you have all initialization files from EE-1.13.

Comment: I wish it was that simple, but that module is present -- `drwxrwxr-x  6 apache dev 4096 Nov 11 12:38 Mview`

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: I have all the files. In looking through table core_resource, I see that the upgrade installs did not actually fire off. Everything is still set to version 1.6, 1.11 or 1.12 -- nothing is at 1.13. Admin is showing version 1.13.1.0 but missing the new 1.13 functionality... Back to ground zero.

Comment: In `core_resource` table version columns contain information about module versions and not magento version. For example in my magento 1.13 installation I have only four extensions with version 1.13. Everything else is low.

Comment: Correct, but I have no 1.13.x module updates. Something else is failing...

Comment: Did you completely clear content of var/cache folder?

Comment: Yes. As it turns out, the issue was (embarrassingly) that I had failed to copy over app/etc/modules, so none of the new modules were installing. We keep app/etc in a separate repository than the Magento core files. I figured this out thanks to your suggestion to look at the app/etc directory. Now I also see `enterprise_cataloginventory_setup 1.13.0.0, enterprise_catalogsearch_setup 1.13.0.0, enterprise_catalog_setup 1.13.0.9, enterprise_index_setup 1.13.0.1` in _core\_resource_.